# Android: writing string to SharedPreferences does not work

Tags: android, json, hashmap, sharedpreferences

I want to convert a HashMap to an JSON so I can write it to my apps Shared Preferences as a string.

So this is what I got so far:

```
    HashMap<String, String> colorHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    colorHashMap.put("test", "test");
    colorHashMap.put("ROT","#FF0000");

    JSONObject colorHashMapJasonObj = new JSONObject(colorHashMap);

    String JSONString = String.valueOf(colorHashMapJasonObj);
    Log.v("JSON: ", JSONString);

    editor.putString("standard_colors_JSON", String.valueOf(colorHashMapJasonObj));
    String JSONcolorStringFromSP = prefs.getString("standard_colors_JSON", "nothting");
    Log.v("JSONcolorStringFromSP: ", JSONcolorStringFromSP);
```

at `JSONString` I get the correct value. but at `JSONcolorStringFromSP` I only get the standard value. So something happens when I try to write my String to my SharedPreferences. But I can't figure out what's wrong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing an `apply()` or a `commit()`? Where's your `SharedPreferences` instance? Here's a complete example:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = ...;
prefs.edit().putString("somekey", "somevalue").apply();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the commit() after put some data
eg:

```
editor.putString("standard_colors_JSON", String.valueOf(colorHashMapJasonObj)).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

All SharedPreferences edits have to be called with a `.commit()` before they're actually saved. Like so:

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = GaggleApplication.getInstance().getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILE, 0).edit();
    editor.putString(name, value);
    editor.commit();
```